# DRF ListSerializer and ListField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I use django rest in my project and until now for list of objects I used [ListSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer), when I needed to have min length and max length of list I googled and reached to [ListField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield).

Before that my code worked fined without any error and misbehavior. Now I use ListField for my list field serializer, But I didn't get when to use ListSerializer? Can someone explain the difference between ListSerializer and FieldSerializer?

My sample code with ListSerializer:

```
tags = serializers.ListSerializer(child=serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False), required=False)
```

My sample code with ListField:

```
open_hour = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DictField(), max_length=7, min_length=7)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer**: This answer is *not complete*

> Can someone explain the difference between ListSerializer and
>   FieldSerializer?

I assume the question is **difference between `serializers.ListSerializer` and `serializers.ListField`**
Suppose we have two `models` as

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} : {self.artist}'
```

and `serializer` as

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Album


class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    AlbumSerializer(many=True, source='album_set')

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Musician
```

**ListSerializer**
As stated in official [DRF doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer)

> When a serializer is instantiated and `many=True` is passed, a
>   ListSerializer instance will be created. The serializer class then
>   becomes a `child` of the parent ListSerializer

For example, we could re-write the `MusicianSerializer` with `ListSerializer` as

```
class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    albums = serializers.ListSerializer(child=AlbumSerializer(), source='album_set')

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Musician
```

it would produce the results same as before. But, if we are trying to use `ListField` instead of `ListSerializer` It will raise an error

```
'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

When I checked the source code, I found that both `ListSerializer` and `ListField` are inherited from the same class (parent and grand parent are same)

Comment: If I need a field that is a list of some type like String or Dict, which one is better to use? and why? I used both and code works fine! I'm kinda confused.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm also a little bit confused :( Hope someone will answer this better way

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and I believe I found a solution!

The trick is you need to create a new Serializer that inherits the ListSerializer class and override the to_representation() method to output your desired format.

If you look at the DRF source code for ListSerializer you can see the default to_representation() method looks like the following...

```
def to_representation(self, data):
        """
        List of object instances -> List of dicts of primitive datatypes.
        """
        # Dealing with nested relationships, data can be a Manager,
        # so, first get a queryset from the Manager if needed
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data

        return [
            self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
        ]
```

**Example**

models

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} : {self.artist}'
```

serializers

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Album

class AlbumKeyValueSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        reaction_count_set = {}
        for item in data.all():
            reaction_count_set[item.name] = item.artist

        return reaction_count_set

class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    AlbumKeyValueSerializer(child=AlbumSerializer(), source='album_set')

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Musician
```

Comment: The exact question is `Can someone explain the difference between ListSerializer and FieldSerializer?` and I don't know what was the problem you solved! Pleas explain your problem

Comment: What is `reaction_count_set` being used for in this example? I'm confused about its purpose, as the original question has no mention of a reaction field. I want to use this as an example but im very confused.