# DRF: Full Example of ListSerializer like Django's Admin-Inline?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to wrap my mind around DRF's ListSerializer in combination with a foreignkey-model. The aim is to have something similar to Django's admin-inline Formula. Unfortunately, I can not find a full example on the documentation or SO examples: two models, two serializers and a viewset.

Suppose we have a model bit like in the SO example [DRF ListSerializer and ListField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489952/drf-listserializer-and-listfield) :

```py
class Musician(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

So I try to put them in serializers like that:

```py
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = 'artist', 'title'
        model = Album

class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = 'name', 'comment', 'albums'
        model = Musician

    albums = serializers.ListSerializer(child=AlbumSerializer(), source='album_set')
```

And then I want to build a ModelViewSet on it, so that I can work with it, just like in Django-Admin-Inline. But this is not working just like that:

```py
class MusicianViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Musician.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MusicianSerializer
```

But it's difficult to test, the HTML front-end does work, and in the tests I got (in a slightly different situation) an error message something like:

`{'album_set': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}`

which I could not understand, not even after digging hours in the source code.
So what am I missing? And ideally, what would be a full working example with POST, PUT and DESTROY, creating modifying oder deleting on child model objects?

[Edit: I'm using Django==4.0.1 and django-extensions==3.1.5]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `related_name` in your model

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='albums')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

then call it in your serializer

```
class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    albums = AlbumSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'comment', 'albums']
        model = Musician
```

Comment: Well imho this is not enough. the `"albums"` don't even show up in the HTML API. And trying to fill in the JSON in **Raw data** directly gives me lot of strange error messages.

Comment: Ok, there are no "strange error messages" (my mistake). But in the current state, it just ignores the `"albums"` data of the sent JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there were different mistakes, and here are some hints to split the problem.
First there were two mistakes in the serializers, we must not serialize the parent `artist`, and we shall add a `create` method to the Musician serializer:

```py
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = 'title',
        model = Album


class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = 'id', 'name', 'comment', 'albums',
        model = Musician

    albums = AlbumSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        album_data = validated_data.pop('albums')
        muse = Musician.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for alb in album_data:
            muse.albums.create(**alb)
        return muse
```

This can be tested directly in tests, here are some hints both for relation serializing and indirectly for writing tests about the Serializer:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ .

With this, I could run a django script through the `runscript` django-extension command, both with `rest_framework.test.RequestsClient` and with `requests.Session` (in the later case, we are shall start the server with the `runserver` command).

The script could look like this:

```py
def run():
    client = requests.Session()
    client.auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)

   TEST_DATA = {
       "name": "Miles Davis",
       "comment": "Great Stuff",
       "albums": [{"title": "B.B."}, {"title": "Don't know"}],
    }
    response = client.post(create_music_url, json=TEST_DATA)
```

I found this useful to understand that the code is right and that the test was wrong, which I still can't get to work...

[Edit] Here are the error messages in the test using the `rest_framework.test.APITestCase` and its `self.client` and `force_authenticate` :

```
   response = self.client.post(music_url, json=TEST_DATA)
```

The `response.data` is the following:
`{'name': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'albums': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}`

and with

```
   response = self.client.post(music_url, TEST_DATA)
```

I get
`{'albums': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}`

Imho, these error messages are confusing to say the least...

Comment: I finally got it, I need to add `format="json"` to my `client.post` call . Uff...